# How to use open weather API to get list of weather stations

Tags: api, openweathermap

I am trying to use the API from [this link](https://openweathermap.org/stations)

Specifically, I would like to get all the weather stations. I think I should use this API:

[image]

Here is the link I have tried so far:

```
https://api.openweathermap.org/data/3.0/stations/?appid=ba1ea204c72ac863c39f442476b8bc71
```

It displays an Internal error. Where did I make a mistake? I am pretty sure that my application `id` is correct and has no issues.

I also tried this API call:

```
https://api.openweathermap.org/data/3.0/stations/583436dd9643a9000196b8d6?appid=ba1ea204c72ac863c39f442476b8bc71
```

It returned a `state not found` error. However, from the API documentation I see as follows:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you might misunderstand what that API set is for. This set is for managing data coming in from hand-curated lists of weather stations - if you knew a station whose data you wished to keep track of, you'd POST the station to your account, then update it with relevant measurements of temp, wind speed, etc. from that station.

The first GET call you list is therefore *not* for listing "all weather stations in existence," rather, it's for listing all of your weather stations that you have added to your account in this way, attributed to your api key, which I would recommend keeping private for future reference ;)

Regardless, if you wanted to successfully call that GET, remove the last slash before the question mark:

`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/3.0/stations?appid=ba1ea204c72ac863c39f442476b8bc71`

In your case, just an empty list will be returned, since you have not added any custom weather stations to your account via the previously listed POST methods on that page.

The second part of your question about why the call with the specified station id does not work - the id in question is an id of an example custom station, again, not a specific one that openweathermap.org has, but the same one used in their examples.

Comment: How do you come to "know a station whose data you wished to keep track of"? Is there a way to get a list of stations near you?