# Get list of weather stations available in openweathermap API

Tags: python, openweathermap, temperature, weather-api

I am trying to look for open source air temperature data providers and finally landed with openweathermap. Does it provide temperature measurements taken by personal sensors (Wikipedia says airport weather stations, on-ground radar stations, weather satellites, remote sensing satellites, METAR and automated weather stations)? If so, is there a way to get the list of available weather stations in the API if provided with a bounding box (using Python, because I did the same with netatmo)?

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62661574/how-to-use-open-weather-api-to-get-list-of-weather-stations) and looked into [this](https://openweathermap.org/stations#additional) in openweathermap's official documentation, but it gives the list of weather stations added to my account. Besides, I have checked other sources like netatmo, tomorrow.io (space based temperature data) and wunderground (no more free api). Please direct me to more free air temperature API providers which get data from personal weather stations.